# External JSON request failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

When I try to get a External json object I receive "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" every time. I already tried use json and jsonp to get these values, but never works.

Here is the link: http://177.54.57.242:8080/ws_VerifSenhaPac_RetJSON?aPaciente=181927&aSenha=MVCARS1

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //evento quando clicar no link com id="pegar-valor"
    jQuery("#pegar-valor").click(function(){

        //pegamos o valor do input
        var usuario = jQuery("input[name=usuariologin]").val();
        var senha = jQuery("input[name=usuariosenha]").val();

        //mostramos o valor com alert()
        //jQuery(this).attr('href', 'http://177.54.57.242:8080/ws_VerifSenhaPac_RetJSON?aPaciente=' + usuario + '&aSenha=' + senha + '');

        //var url = 'http://177.54.57.242:8080/ws_VerifSenhaPac_RetJSON?aPaciente=' + usuario + '&aSenha=' + senha + '?callback=?';
        var url = "http://177.54.57.242:8080/ws_VerifSenhaPac_RetJSON?aPaciente=181927&aSenha=MVCARS1&callback=?";

        jQuery.getJSON( url, function ( result ) {
            var objeto = JSON.parse( result );
            console.log(objeto.StatusSenha);
        });

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://177.54.57.242:8080/ws_VerifSenhaPac_RetJSON?aPaciente=181927&aSenha=MVCARS&?callback=?',
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
               console.log('teste');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

where is your JSON saved, it happened to me couple of days ago, i saved a JSON in database field, i had to save it like text, when i wanted to retrieve the value it returned with quotes "", and i was having the same error because quoted text is taken as string instead json, you have to check if the place where you are storing that json it '{JSON_CONTENT HERE}' if its stored like "'{}'", then is wrong.

Comment: The Json are external from a different system and server. Well, the way like the json is beeing save is on that link.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your response is json and not jsonp. Try with `dataType: "json"`